# Get Unix timestamp (in seconds) for a hg commit

Tags: date, mercurial

Given a commit with the date `Mon Aug 18 21:05:38 2014 +0200`, how can I get the Unix timestamp of it in seconds?

The following command produces a number that discards the number (presumably because the timezone information of `date` got discarded):

```
$ hg log -l1 --template '{date(date, "%s")}\n'
1408392338
$ date -d@1408392338
Mon Aug 18 22:05:38 CEST 2014
```

I am effectively looking for the equivalent of the `git` command that produces the commit date as a Unix timestamp:

```
git log -n1 --pretty=%ct
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requested timestamp was one that is independent of the timezone, so UTC time. As `date(..., "%s")` produces a number which is relative to the current timezone, one should request a UTC output by combining the `localdate` filter with the `TZ` environment variable to set a timezone:

```
TZ=UTC hg log -l1 --template '{date(date|localdate, "%s")}\n')
```

Comment: Why not just `--template "{localdate(date,'UTC')|date}\n"` ?

Comment: @rdb Either it did not exist at the time or I was unaware of it. Consider posting your suggestion as answer and if possible, some documentation references.

Comment: @Lekensteyn You're correct, it didn't exist at the time. The `localdate` filter was turned into a function on [2015-09-01](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/rev/7012be5ab5bd).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to take the first field produced from the template format `{date|hgdate}`, which is already in UTC. The second field in this format just gives the timezone, and can be discarded by applying Mercurial's `word` function within the format specifier. Here is a test of this format against the system `date` command and your own (correct, but longer) answer, on Mercurial 3.7.3:

```
$ date +%s && hg commit -m 'ok'
1539258496
$ TZ=UTC hg log -l1 --template '{date(date|localdate, "%s")}\n'
1539258496
$ hg log -l1 -r. --template '{date|hgdate}'
1539258496 -7200
$ hg log -l1 --template '{word(0, date|hgdate)}'
1539258496
```

The correctness is also confirmed by the description in the `hg` manpage of the `hgdate` filter:

> **hgdate** Date. Returns the date as a pair of numbers: "1157407993 25200" (Unix timestamp, timezone offset).

(Side note: The timezone offset, a little confusingly, is negated: I'm in UTC+2, but the offset is given as -7200 seconds. However, this is only important if you want the local time. If you're after UTC, you will be ignoring the offset in any case.)

Overall, the `date|hgdate` variant only saves a few characters, but personally I find it conceptually cleaner and easier to understand. It may also be a little more robust against potential future bugs in Mercurial, since it involves fewer parsing and formatting operations.

Answer (score 0):

- You can get date of changeset in *any* format, which understand `-d` option of date and use it in `date -d -F`
- You can use keyword *with filter*

Sample

```
hg log -r tip -T "date: {date}\nhgdate: {date|hgdate}\nISO-date: {date|isodate}\n"
date: 1390885140.0-21600
hgdate: 1390885140 -21600
ISO-date: 2014-01-28 10:59 +0600
```

I think (too lazy to test), result of expression `1390885140-21600` will give you correct timestamp

Comment: I did try `date|hgdate`, but besides the odd formatting, it did not give the expected result. Apparently, the first field is the local time, so to get UTC one has to subtract (rather than add) the second field.